# I am trying to drop MySQL database but it's showing an error in console

Tags: mysql

In console I am trying to drop database using command

```
drop database database_name;
```

But it's throwing the below error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'database check' at line 1

I also tried to use another command:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p drop check;
```

It is throwing an error below

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqladmin -u root -p drop check' at line 1

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

`CHECK` is a reserved word in MySQL, you should use back-tick character to escape it:

```
DROP DATABASE `check`;
```

In future, try to avoid using reserved words as names of tables/databases to prevent such things from happening.